# Select statement takes too long to finish

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query,

```
SELECT  1
FROM    orderdetail               -- table orderdetail has 1420703 rows
WHERE   orderdetailstatusid != 3  -- not cancelled
AND
navdate = '20161212';
```

The problem is that it takes more than 130 seconds to execute since its scanning a huge table with ~1420703 rows. I was wondering if there is a way to make it a bit faster.

I tried to do `limit 1` at the end but that also did not help.

Can some one please give some suggestion, how to improve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you any indexes on the table? Add the output of `explain select ...`

Comment: Thank you @juergend for responding to my question, I do have indexes on the table but dont have any index with orderdetailstatus or navdate. may be its a good idea to add a new index. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And to add my contribution:

For best performance:

Firstly you should have your 2 columns indexed  as proposed by macco

Secondly,  `!=`/`<>` operator is a perf killer, much more intensive for the engine than `=` operator, and might result in a full table scan. 
When you can, it's always better to list all possible values rather than say *different than value*. 
It looks like it is the case here. So you can rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT  1
FROM  orderdetail               -- table orderdetail has 1420703 rows
WHERE orderdetailstatusid IN (1,2,4,5)  -- everything but cancelled
  AND navdate = '20161212';
```

Supposing that you you can only have `orderdetailstatusid` values like (1,2,3,4,5), change accordingly.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thank you for your reply to my question, indeed it helped a lot, I used `WHERE orderdetailstatusid IN (1,4)` , and it was hell lot of faster than earlier. Thank you so much for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2):

Creating indexes on the table will make it faster.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name1
ON table_name (navdate)

CREATE INDEX index_name2
ON table_name (orderdetailstatusid)
```

Comment: Add index on 'navdate' first then on 'orderdetailstatusid' and if it is suitable to your data then you can change dataype of 'navdate' to INT, now it seems CHAR or VARCHAR because character data comparision is slower than numeric.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding to my question, I will try creating index to see if it gets any faster.Thanks again!!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT  1

FROM orderdetail With(NOLOCK)

WHERE orderdetailstatusid != 3  -- not cancelled

AND navdate = '20161212';

Comment: With(NOLOCK) Allow you execute the Query Faster Then you expect as It's Does not Allow Locking over the Table

Comment: Hi Alfaiz, Thank you for your suggestion, I will surely try this. I had no idea about `NOLOCK` thingie. Thanks :)